# How can I ignore the first rows of my input table?

Tags: tables, pgfplots, input

How can I ignore this part of my table (input)

```
Component: sigX

X-Achse:
clasWidth = 1.2
borderDown = -335.4
maxClas = 200

Y-Achse:
clasWidth = 1.2
borderDown = 0
maxClas = 200
```

My data for the diagram should start here (in this row): mean range count

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[enlargelimits=0.2,colorbar,
    view={0}{90}  % view the plot from the top
]
\addplot3[
    scatter,mark=diamond*,only marks,
    point meta=\thisrow{count},
    z buffer=sort  
]
table {
Component: sigX

X-Achse:
clasWidth = 1.2
borderDown = -335.4
maxClas = 200

Y-Achse:
clasWidth = 1.2
borderDown = 0
maxClas = 200

mean    range   count 
-220.8  228 50045
-222    201.6   50045
-220.2  198 200176
-224.4  196.8   200176
-220.8  192 200176
-221.4  190.8   50044
-226.2  176.4   200176
-199.2  156 50044
-201.6  153.6   50045
-219    147.6   50044
-252.6  133.2   50044
-210    129.6   200176
-250.8  127.2   50044
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. You can start all lines that should be ignored with either `#` or `%` which then are ignored (see [section 4.3.2 in the PGFPlots manual on page 49 (v1.14)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=49)). Is that what you where asking for?

Answer (score 6):

The `skip first n` key does this. Use `\addplot [...] table [skip first n=12,x=mean,y=range] {...`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[enlargelimits=0.2,colorbar,
    view={0}{90}  % view the plot from the top
]
\addplot3[
    scatter,mark=diamond*,only marks,
    point meta=\thisrow{count},
    z buffer=sort  
]
table [skip first n=12,x=mean,y=range] {
Component: sigX

X-Achse:
clasWidth = 1.2
borderDown = -335.4
maxClas = 200

Y-Achse:
clasWidth = 1.2
borderDown = 0
maxClas = 200

mean    range   count 
-220.8  228 50045
-222    201.6   50045
-220.2  198 200176
-224.4  196.8   200176
-220.8  192 200176
-221.4  190.8   50044
-226.2  176.4   200176
-199.2  156 50044
-201.6  153.6   50045
-219    147.6   50044
-252.6  133.2   50044
-210    129.6   200176
-250.8  127.2   50044
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know how I can skip the second row if my table consists of a .cxv file structured as x;y \n 0;0 \n 1;3 \n 2;8 \n ...? I tried using skip first n but then pgfplots doesn't find the names x and y anymore. I also tried using 'skip rows between index' but then I get the error ' I do not know the key '/tikz/skip rows between index' I am using \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

Comment: @BartWolleswinkel Probably you found an answer already, but anyway I don't have any good ones. Perhaps you could do `skip first n=2` and use numerical indexes instead of columns names, i.e. `x index=0` instead of `x=x`.